# Charset issues with Datatables.net, PHP and MySQL

Tags: codeigniter, character-encoding, datatables

I am having issues displaying data from MySQL in datatables(.net) containing Norwegian characters (Æ, Ø, Å, etc.). I'm running CodeIgniter and have the following variables configured in database.php:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

I am also using utf8_encode on data from forms before inserting it into the database, but when I extract the data thing gets displayed. The database is also configured with utf8_general_ci. In short my question is: how should I configure CodeIgniter and MySQL to be able to both insert and extract data from the database without issues ? Should I use utf8_encode before submitting the data or is that just double encoding and a part of the issue ?

PS! I don't think datatables are part of the problem since the field is already empty when data gets sent to the datatables.

PS2! I'm not sure why, but I'm only facing issues with uppercase norwegian letters. Ø fails to display, but ø work fine. Å fails to display, but å works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last week & I figured out that it wasn’t the DB that had problem but it was the way the Codeigniter transacts the data.

So every time before saving the data in the database, I pass the data through

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

And before showing the data in html, I again pass it through

```
html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8')
```

Just for record, I have this in my DB Config file

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
mysql_select_db('db_name');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Put `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` after select database line